# why '==' is returning false even after my hashcode value is same

Tags: java, object, hash, reference, hashcode

I have a written a class like

```
public class HashCodeImpl{
    public int hashCode(){
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HashCodeUtil h=  new HashCodeUtil();
        HashCodeUtil h1=  new HashCodeUtil();
        System.out.println(h.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h);
        System.out.println(h1);
        System.out.println(h==h1);
    }
}
```

OutPut:

```
1 
com.manu.test.HashCodeUtil@1  
com.manu.test.HashCodeUtil@1 false
```

My question is: when my hashCode method is returning same value then why
`System.out.println(h==h1);` 
is coming false?

Please explain.

Comment: Where did you read that if two hashcode are the same then the references must be the same? `a.equals(b) => a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`, that's the only thing you can know (not mentioning that you have to redefine properly equals and hashcode).

Comment: use .equals, == is reference equality

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java - note the references to Effective Java in the answers, a must read.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are two different object references. `==` compare the references, not the `hashCode` results.

To get a desired result, you may override the `equals` method in your class and use `h1.equals(h2)` to see if they're equivalent. Here you may use the result of `hashCode` to ease the evaluation of the equality of the objects being compared (this doesn't mean that two objects with the same hash code are equals).

But note that even if the objects have the same `hashCode` and are equivalent by the definition of the `equals` method, they are different references that occupy a different place in the heap.

Comment: "... because of the `new` keyword" that creates a new object instance using the constructor".

Answer (score 0):

As @ZouZou points out, `hashCode` equality does not equate to object equality.  Having said that, you are not even comparing for object equality.  Comparing two objects with `==` is a reference equality check, which you should almost never use, unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Ummm ... comparing two `String`s with `==` is something you should almost never do.  (Actually, I say _never_, period.)  But I don't think you can say the same about objects in general.  Some objects represent _values_, and in those cases there should be an `equals` method and you should use that instead of `==`.  But not all objects are value objects, and I don't think this holds for those other objects.

Comment: I did not say never, I said almost never.  Also, if you've written a proper .equals method, it's first check should be for reference equality.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of the `hashCode`.  As others have pointed out, `==` compares references and not hash codes.  However, an overriding `equals` method, which compares values and not references, still wouldn't compare hash codes.

Think about it ... A hash code is an `int`, and therefore there are only 2<sup>32</sup> possible values for a hash code.  But how many possible `String`s are there?  Many, many more than 2<sup>32</sup>.  (Since each `char` has 2<sup>16</sup> possible values, there are 2<sup>48</sup> possible `String`s of length three, and the number just keeps growing the longer the `String`s get.)  Therefore, it is impossible to set up a scheme where two `String`s are always equal if their hash codes are equal.  The same is true of most other objects (although a class with a relatively small number of possible values could be set up with a unique hash code for each value).

The `hashCode`'s purpose is to come up with a number that can be used for a `hashMap` or `hashSet`.  We often try to come up with a function that will reduce that chance that unequal objects have unequal hash codes, in order to improve the efficiency of the map or set.  But for most objects, of course, it's impossible to guarantee this.